# Recognize mouseon <td> of table and insert into values

Tags: javascript

First of all I don't wanna use jQuery or other libraries - pure JS.

My target is to build drag & drop items (that part I've already done), when you drag an item on the table cell (`<td>`), it (`<td>`) will change his `background color`, and when I drop the item into the `<td>` it should change the current color to the other color.

I think that I need to detect when an item is on a `<td>`, how do I do it, and how do I know which `<td>` I should change.

Comment: Try using onmouseover event.

Comment: My question is how to detect if the user is on a table cell and which table cell it is (because there are a lot of table cells).

Comment: I hope you don't mind my asking: why do you need not to use JQuery or other libraries?

Comment: It's a question. I should solve it only with pure JS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onmouseover` for this,

```
document.getElementById(id).onmouseover = function() {//do something};
```

Comment: Should I give each cell an 'id' and than turn on that function for each cell? it doesn't look the best practice.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```
var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];

function colorCell(e){
    var cell = e.target;
    cell.style.backgroundColor = '#f00';
}

table.addEventListener('mouseover', colorCell, false);
```

Or, you could bind directly to the `td` elements themselves:

```
var cells = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for (var i = 0, len = cells.length; i < len; i++) {
    cells[i].addEventListener('mouseover', colorCell, false);
    /* or:
    cells[i].onmouseover = colorCell;
    */
}
```

Comment: The table is under the element (which I'm dragging into the table), so it doesn't recognize 'mouseover' because the 'mouseover' is refer to the element I'm dragging.